# Splitting varieties of two Galois cohomology symbols

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-cohomology

One important property of the so called norm varieties defined by Rost, is that they split pure symbols of Galois cohomology groups $H^n(k,\mu_p)$:

For some $\alpha \in H^n(k,\mu_p)$ there is a smooth, projective $X_\alpha$ such that

$X_\alpha$ has a $L$-rational point iff $\alpha = 0$ in $H^n(L,\mu_p)$ for all extensions $L/k$.

We call such a variety a splitting variety for $\alpha$.

Lets assume we have non trivial, pure symbols $\alpha \in H^n(k,\mu_p)$ and $\beta \in H^m(k,\mu_l)$ for different primes $p,l$.

Is there an example of a variety $X$ which is a splitting variety for both symbols $\alpha, \beta$ i.e. is it possible to construct such a thing?

Is it possible when we restrict our definition to field extensions of dimension $p*l$ ?

Comment: You should ask this question on MathOverflow.

Comment: Thats funny. I originally intended to do so,but i thought it might be obvious to the pro's that it makes no sense to ask this due to some facts i have no idea of.